# Is it possible to make an element inside a container bigger than the container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say the I have a container with a width of 900px, all the posts inside are 900px.

I want to make the first one to be 100% (not 900px but as big as the screen).

Would that be possible?

```css
#container { width: 900px; background: red; }
.post { width: 900px; height: 50px; background: yellow; margin: 0 0 10px;  }
.post:first-child { background: green; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="post">Post 1</div>
  <div class="post">Post 2</div>
  <div class="post">Post 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the given style a width of `100%` would be as wide as your `container` so you can use [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length), e.g.

```
.post:first-child { width : 100vw; }
```

(`1vw` is equal to 1% of the width of your viewport)

Comment: and also pay attention to overflow (even if it's visible by default)

Comment: You need few adjustments, but check if is this result: https://codepen.io/joaosaro/pen/PQQOMv

Answer (score 1):

@fcalderan is correct. As an addition, I want to add that it is possible that you have a centred container, in which case you'd want some repositioning.

Explanation: move the box to the left (negative `margin-left`), by a value of half the screen (`50vw`) minus half of the container (`50%`). Basically: move the box from its current position to the right, i.e. so that the left hand side is aligned to the center of the page (`+50%` of container width) and then move it back half of the page to the left (`-50vw`).

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.post {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.post:first-child {
  background: green;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(-1 * (50vw - 50%));
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="post">Post 1</div>
  <div class="post">Post 2</div>
  <div class="post">Post 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can do this, I wouldn't advise it... essentially you are asking for all kinds of problems when it comes to resizing and finding issues.

There are a few better options... Have the post outside the container, or simply have the container full-width, and restrict the width of the other posts.

```
#container { width: 100%; background: red; }
.post { width: 900px; height: 50px; background: yellow; margin: 0 0 10px;  }
.post:first-child { width: 100%; background: green; }


<div id="container">
  <div class="post">Post 1</div>
  <div class="post">Post 2</div>
  <div class="post">Post 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 50px;
  }
.post { 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 50px; 
  background: yellow; 
  margin: 0 0 10px;  
  }
.post:first-child { 
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="post">Post 1</div>
  <div class="post">Post 2</div>
  <div class="post">Post 3</div>
  <div class="post">Post 3</div>
  <div class="post">Post 4</div>
  <div class="post">Post 5</div>
  <div class="post">Post 6</div>
  <div class="post">Post 7</div>
  <div class="post">Post 8</div>
  <div class="post">Post 9</div>
  <div class="post">Post 10</div>
  <div class="post">Post 11</div>
  <div class="post">Post 12</div>
  <div class="post">Post 13</div>
  <div class="post">Post 14</div>
</div>
```